# Bulk Insert in Oracle table 10g without stored procedure/avoid loop

Tags: c#, xml, database, oracle, datatable

I have a datatable of 3 columns `ID (int), Name (string), Status (string)` and of 1000 rows .. and a table with 4 columns `seq` (generated from `SEQR.NEXTVAL`), `ID`, `Name`, `Status`.

I want to insert all 1000 rows in a single query. I mean avoiding 1000 times database hit using loops for performance issue.

Constraints are:

1. I am using Oracle 10g
2. stored procedures, cursors not allowed
3. To temporary table creation allowed as DBA is from client side so I can't create DB tables from my side

Any suggestion with proper code? I am using Oracle client and `DbCommand` object

Answer (score 2):

So just use a single SQL statement, right?

```
insert into table_a (seq_col, id, name, status)
select seqr.nextval, id, name, status
from table_b;
```

Comment: But here one table is datatable another is database table

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use a Select statement in your insert statement:

```
Insert into table2
  Select SEQR.NEXTVAL, tab1.*
    from table1 as tab1
```

Comment: @RahulChowdhury So you want to write a `query` from .Net side and insert a 1000 rows in one trip to the server. I am now aware of a way to do that. Why cant you use stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle array DML. YOu just fill the column arrays in a loop from your code, and the send everything as a single INSERT statement.
Anyway IMHO 1000 INSERTs with a properly written query using bind variables won't hit performance issues. You'll get them if you don't use bind variables and commit each time...